# CSS Animation Support

Tags: css, animation

I'm using keyframes to add animation to parts of my website. The animation is a fade in with the page content. My question is if the user loads the site in an unsupported browser, will the text load on the page, or will it not be appear (because of no animation support)?

Comment: It depends on the code.  Can we see some?

Comment: You can test this quite easily. Remove the animation keyframe (or anything else to make the animation happen) and refresh the page. If the text shows then yes, it will show on browsers that don't support animations

Comment: Digitalfront: the code is just an animation from 0% to 100% with keyframes. @ZachSaucier can you make that an answer?

Comment: @ShaanSingh I did as you requested

Comment: @ZachSaucier okay, thanks. I'll be testing each one and reporting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test yourself this quite easily. Remove the animation keyframe (or anything else to make the animation happen) and refresh the page. If the text shows then yes, it will show on browsers that don't support animations

As for the actual animation itself, without seeing it it is hard to tell. If the text's default is to be transparent, have an opacity of 0, or have `display:none` to start out with then it will likely not show up on browsers that do not support CSS3 animations.

On a side note, CSS3 animations have [pretty good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) given you use browser prefixes for the older browsers

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations are defined with "to" and "from" or a bunch of keyframes "xx%". But before the animation launches (or if it doesn't launch) and after it has finished, all properties are defined by the rest of the stylesheet, and whatever is in the keyframes has no effect.